# Retrieve notes saved in Outlook meeting that was rescheduled

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

If I am a meeting attendee (not organizer) and save notes within the calendar item, and then that calendar item/meeting is updated by the organizer, are my notes lost and irretrievable?

I'm trying to help a coworker who, over the past three months, has been compiling notes within a meeting item she did not create.  That meeting was recently updated by the organizer and now all of her notes are gone... which really blows my mind.  Why would she be allowed to open, edit, and "save" notes in a calendar item if they will not be persisted if the meeting is rescheduled/updated?

Comment: the whole thing sounds very odd, i would recommend trying to recreate the scenario, sometime people say odd things and the mean something else

Comment: She is allowed to do it, but when it was rescheduled, the old appointment was deleted and a new appointment was created

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Recover Deleted Items from Outlook Client on Windows and Outlook for Web Access. Both give slightly different ways to recover deleted items. It is not clear if the calendar entry is deleted then re-added, so you may or may not be able to [recover deleted items](https://portal.office.com/support/help.aspx?sid=recdelitems&CorrelationId=865667fa-776b-4ebd-a33b-692a135e4bd2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#/).

Comment: I've had the same thing happen to me, the appointment is not deleted. So you won't find it in deleted items. It appears that when you edit the meeting notes and save the meeting, it is only saved on your end, not sent to the organiser. Then if the organiser updates the meeting your local changes are dropped. Am trying to figure out how to find the previous (local) version of the meeting.

Comment: I'm thinking your local notes are just overwritten and there is no version history. Unless you keep regular backups of the PST or OST, How would one recover such notes? I know there are tools that can use Outlook as a datasource, so you could conceivably historical versions, but it'd be quite the task to make constant backups of your Outlook.